# Downloading a video from a link in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails project which is using the liveclicker video player. To be able to add a downloading feature to my webapp, I've been implemented a link to be able, to download the video. I want to do that with a link_to and call a method inside the corresponding controller to download the video. Can anyone help me to implement my method to be able to download the video from that URL to my local machine?

I have this code in the controllers index method.

```
def index
  send_file 'website', :type=>"video/mp4", :x_sendfile=>true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

please consider inserting the code you already have. My proposal is to use the [send_data](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data) within the action you are referring the link to. Try to write the implementation and if you have more questions, the people here will be happy to help you agin ...

Answer (score 0):

Install [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to your server

```
src = "http://example.com/video.avi"   
system %x{ wget -P ~/where/ever/you/want/folder #{src} }
```

Since downloading is a long process, take a look at [background process gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Background_Jobs)