# Ruby on Rails - Enabling client to download videos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Requirement - I have a video hosted on my server, User should be able to download the file by clicking the link.

I am following the instructions given at http://code.runnable.com/Upd0g0q7JxN6AAIE/how-to-download-a-file-using-ruby-on-rails- to download video files.

It is taking lot of time to download, and after that it opens the binary file in browser.

Controller - EDITED - Complete Controller

```
class YoutubeDownloadsController < ApplicationController

def index
end

def download
    link = params[:link]
    #YoutubeDL.download "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvdf5n-zI14", output: Rails.public_path.join('downloads','some_file.mp4')
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json
        format.js
    end
end

def browser_download
    send_file Rails.public_path.join('downloads', 'some_file.mp4'), :type=>"video/mp4", :x_sendfile=>true
end
end
```

View -

index.html.erb

```
<div class="card">
  <header class="card-header bg-inverse text-white">
    <h3 class="text-left font-weight-bold">Download Videos <small class="font-italic">...for free</small></h3>
  </header>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-8" style="margin-top:15%;margin-left:10em;margin-right:10em;">
  <%= form_tag("/download",method:"post", remote: true) do %>
    <div class="input-group">
      <%=  text_field_tag 'link', nil, placeholder: 'Paste your youtube link ...', class: "form-control" %>
      <!--input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Paste your youtube link ..."-->
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <%= button_tag "Download!", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <!--button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Go!</button-->
      </span>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div id='file'></div>
  <br>
  <small><p class="text-muted" style="margin-left:20em;margin-right:20em;">Please thank good samaritans @ <a href="https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/">Youtube-dl</a>. They made it possible.</p></small>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <footer class="text-right card-footer text-muted bg-info text-white" >
    <small><p>Posted by: Tushar Saurabh | Contact information: <a href="mailto:tusharacc@gmail.com">Email Me</a>.</p></small>
  </footer>
</div>
```

download.js.erb

```
var html = '<a href="<%=  browser_download_path %>">Download</a>';
document.getElementById('file').innerHTML = html
```

Route -

```
get '/browser_download', to: 'download#browser_download'
```

The binary file - 
[image]

How can I avoid opening of the file in browser. Moreover, the process is slow, is there a better and faster way to do it.

Comment: Share your more code so that we can help you

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari, I have added the complete code base.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415483/downloading-a-video-from-a-link-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684508/download-video-from-url-in-ruby-on-rails and if your are using paperclip then refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132806/saving-video-files-in-rails